# Impossible to send events from more than one non-domain windows server (2008, 2003) to WinRM collector (windows 2012)

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate, forwarding, winrm

We have problem with non-domain servers using certificates. We created certificates (through CA), installed one on collector (with good CN), second on first source server, third on second source server. First source server can connect to collector without problem and send events to them. Second source server can't register to collector and get error "Access denied". But if we drop first source server from subscription and add second source server to subscription, then second source server can register to collector and is sending events to them without problem. We found issue, that only one (first connected) source server can send events to collector even if we have more server in subscription configuration.

We try run collector on Windows 2012 and Windows 2012 R2 server with same issue.

We found that similar issue for Windows 2008 R2 server exist: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2884172. This issue is part of package https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355 for Windows 8.1 and Windows 2012 R2, but not for Windows 2012.

Have can we solve this problem on Windows 2012 server ?

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: We didn't test solution for Windows 2012 R2 too. We only found this package.

Comment: KB 2919355 is not resolve this issue. We tested it in our lab.